# LLVM- How to get function by function's real/original name

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

Recently, I use llvm to insert call Instruction in LLVM-IR. The problem is that , if I have a funtion named `add`, I can not find it using getFuntion(string) since the add() in IR may `_Z3addv_`. I know that all fucntion in IR has a new name, but I didn't know what the new name exactly is.

```
  Module *m = f->getParent();
  IRBuilder<> builder(m->getContext());
  Function *call = m->getFunction("add");
  // call is NULL.
  std::vector<Value *> args;
  ......



Module *m = f->getParent();
IRBuilder<> builder(m->getContext());
Function *call = m->getFunction("_Z3addv");
// call is not NULL.
std::vector<Value *> args;
......
```

How can I find the function using its original name?

Comment: The C++ name mangling is done by clang, so look in clang's APIs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may reuse `Mangler` from `LLVMCore`.

Here is an example of usage:

```
std::string mangledName;
raw_string_ostream mangledNameStream(mangledName);
Mangler::getNameWithPrefix(mangledNameStream, "add", m->getDataLayout());
// now mangledName contains, well, mangled name :)
```

Comment: thinks. This is what I want !!!  NOTE:  there should  add `mangledNameStream.flush()` after the 3 lines to flush the buffer, otherwise the mangledname may NULL.

Comment: I have just tried this, but it doesn't seem to work. `mangledName` contains the unmangled name.

Comment: the same with @executor21

Comment: the same with @executor21

Answer (score 1):

libstdc++ has a nice demangling library, just include `cxxabi.h`
Then you can change `Function *call = m->getFunction("_Z3addv");`

to

`int status;
Function *call = m->getFunction(abi::__cxa_demangle("_Z3addv"), nullptr, nullptr, &status);`